# How-To Pass an array to a function which uses func_get_args to retrieve parameter

Tags: php

I am programming to an API method which accepts a variable number of arguments.  The API method (see below) uses func_get_args.  I am wrapping the API, and would like to be able to pass an associative array instead of passing the keys/values of the array as parameters; i.e. `filter(key1,value1,key2,value2 ...)`

I have source code access to the API, but unfortunately I can not change the source.
I have looked at [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), which I believe should/will pass an array as a set of arguments (though not an associative array).  `filter` is a method of an object - I don't know how to pass a method as a callback.  I also don't know if there is a clean way to wrap this API.  Any and all help is appreciated.

```
<?php

public function &filter() {
        $filter = new QueryFilter($this->queryhandler, $this);
        $args = func_get_args();
        $filter->applyFilter($this->getFilters($args));
        return $filter;
    }
```

Comment: What's the deal with `key1`, `key2` etc? `func_get_args` provides a numerically indexed array where the keys are predetermined.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Added an answer.

Comment: The function `filter` takes database field names and field values.  Which is why I would prefer to use an associative array. The associative array will need to be manipulated so the keys and values would be in a non associative array e.g take array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2') and make array('key1','value1','key2','value2'..)  which I can do, but I am not sure how to pass the method as a callback function.  I'm unsure if call_user_func_array is the correct way to do that.

Comment: Thank You - Will up vote once I have a chance to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a wrapper that takes an array and "flattens" the keys and values:

```
function wrapper(array $params) {
    $flat = array();
    foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
        $flat[] = $k;
        $flat[] = $v;
    }

    return call_user_func_array('filter', $flat);
}
```

The above assumes that `filter` is a free function, which in your case isn't true. To specify a method as a callback, use the syntax `array($object, 'filter')` with `call_user_func_array` to call the method `filter` on `$object`.